# google cloud dataprep is choosing the network default

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to run a job in google cloud dataprep , but  the dataflow  job is by default selecting network default . How I can update it to a project specific network

I tried to simulate the problem in dataflow , but  over there there is an option where we can update the network and subnet

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to change this in Dataprep. Dataprep spawns the Dataflow job but there's no option in Dataprep to specify the network and subnetwork for the Dataflow job that will run.

Answer (score 1):

The dataprep team confirmed that  in the next release they will add the functionality to choose the network . It is coming in weeks time from now .